# How to return Firestore snapshot data in nuxt 3 server api

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have an api where I call data from my firestore backend using firebase admin. It works if I use the get() command, but I want to listen to realtime changes. How do I rewrite my code to listen using the onSnapshot() listener and return the value from firestore to my pinia store?

Here's a code representation of what I did to read data once

*server/api/users.ts*

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";
import { db } from "~~/helpers/fireadmin";

export default async (request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse) => {
    const usersSnap = await db.collection('authUsers').get();
    if(usersSnap.empty) return "No user created"
    const users = usersSnap.docs.map((doc) => {
        return {
            uuid: doc.id,
            ...doc.data(),
        }
    })
    
    return users
}
```

*store/users.ts*

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
    state: () => ({
        users: [],
    }),
    actions: {
        async setuser() {
            const { data } = await useAsyncData('users', () => $fetch('/api/users'))
            this.users = data.value
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: `onSnapshot()` functions meant to be used in browser. Instead of API create SSR app and run that function in `if (process.client)` statement.

Comment: But I am using firebase admin sdk, and It runs on the server

Comment: You call onsnapshot in mounted hook in browser. It is for client side only. So load the data from server first and then use onsnapshot on client mounted hook.